# Traversing directory with Boost fails

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having some trouble with the following function. It is supposed to be given a path and a set of allowed file extensions, then find all files in that path with any of those extensions. Instead it finds nothing and returns an empty set.

```
std::set<boostfs::path> scan_directory(const boostfs::path& p,
                                       const bool recurse,
                                       const std::set<std::string>& allowed) {
    std::string ext ;
    std::set<boostfs::path> incs, incs2 ;
    boostfs::path::iterator itr ;

    // Extract directory and filename
    boostfs::path file = p.filename() ;
    boostfs::path dir = p.parent_path() ;

    std::cout << "path: " << p.string() << std::endl ;

    for (itr = dir.begin(); itr != dir.end(); ++itr) {
        if (boostfs::is_directory(*itr)) {
            if (recurse) {
                std::cout << "dir: " << itr->string() << std::endl ;
                incs2 = scan_directory(*itr, true, allowed) ;
                incs.insert(incs2.begin(), incs2.end()) ;
            }
        } else {
            // Don't include the original source
            if (*itr != p) {
                // Include only allowed file types
                ext = itr->extension().string() ;
                std::cout << "file: " << itr->string() << std::endl ;
                std::cout << "ext: " << ext << std::endl ;
                if (allowed.find(ext) != allowed.end()) {
                    incs.insert(*itr) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return incs ;
}
```

The prints to cout are just for debugging. I'm testing it with the following directory structure:

```
./test/cpp/
    foo.cpp
    foo.h
    test.cpp
./test/cpp/bar/
    baz.cpp
    baz.h
```

I invoke the function with the path "test/cpp/test.cpp", recurse true and a set containing one string ".cpp". I get the following output from the prints,

```
path: test/cpp/test.cpp
dir: test
path: test
file: cpp
ext:
```

Then the function ends and the rest of the program continues, only it's given an empty set of files so not much to work on. Given the test directory it should return a set containing "test/cpp/foo.cpp" and "test/cpp/bar/baz.cpp".

I'm fairly sure it worked not long ago, but I'm not sure when it broke or what I did that made it do so. I'm sure it's some small, annoying technicality.

Comment: Note that a better alternative for recursive directory scans is `fs::recursive_directory_iterator`.

Comment: @Xeo Thanks, I'll look into that. Right now I just want to understand what goes wrong here, though.

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: A hint: If your passed path has no parent path, your function does nothing.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've never really used debuggers. I guess it seems that with relatively simple code like this it'd be more work to use a debugger than to just understand the code or insert a few prints here and there.

Comment: @Xeo Good point, but in this case it does, so that not it, right?

Comment: No, the first time you recurse, you pass `"test"` (`p.begin()`) to `scan_directories` and that has no parent path.

Comment: Also, debuggers are the coders best friend. Especially if you have access to a visual debugger for stepping through your source code. Which compiler are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. I was using `path::iterator` instead of `directory_iterator` (or `recursive_directory_iterator`) so I was looping through the components of the path instead of the contents of the directory. I could have sworn it worked earlier, but that might just have been luck maybe.

Here's my working code

```
std::set<boostfs::path> scan_directory(const boostfs::path& p,
                                       const bool recurse,
                                       const std::set<std::string>& allowed) {
    std::string ext ;
    std::set<boostfs::path> incs ;

    // Extract directory and filename
    boostfs::path file = p.filename() ;
    boostfs::path dir = p.parent_path() ;

    boostfs::recursive_directory_iterator itr(dir), itr_end ;

    while(itr != itr_end) {
        if (boostfs::is_directory(*itr)) {
            itr.no_push(!recurse) ;
        } else {
            // Don't include the original source
            if (*itr != p) {
                // Include only allowed file types
                ext = itr->path().extension().string() ;
                if (allowed.find(ext) != allowed.end()) {
                    incs.insert(*itr) ;
                }
            }
        }

        itr++ ;
    }

    return incs ;
}
```

I'll let it be known that the examples of iterating through directories in Boost's documentation are AWFUL

Comment: Glad you found your problem.  You know Boost is open-source right?  You could submit a documentation patch!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm not sure I'm all that qualified, but maybe I could do that.